# RestSharp.RestClient ignores timeout

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, timeout, restsharp

I'm developing a .net core application using RestSharp.RestClient (105.2.4-rc4-24214-01).
I set

```
RestClient.Timeout=1
```

or

```
RestClient.Timeout=10000
```

and then call my test API

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();
RestClient.ExecuteAsync(request, response => { tcs.SetResult(response); })
return tcs.Task.Result;
```

But it still use default value 100000 and generate "A task was canceled." exception only after 100000 ms.

How can  i change this value?

Comment: Are you setting the timeout of the specific RestClient instance that you use to send the request?

Comment: yes, i m sure i am

Comment: Same problem here, I'm setting the Timeout and ReadWriteTimeout and it does not work.

Comment: Same problem... sigh...

Comment: This test passes https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/develop/RestSharp.IntegrationTests/AsyncTests.cs#L200
Is there anything that you do differently?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation says the Request.Timeout overrides the RestClient.Timeout.
Try this:

```
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();
request.Timeout = 10000;
RestClient.ExecuteAsync(request, response => { tcs.SetResult(response); })
return tcs.Task.Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CancellationTokenSource and use its token to abort the handle to response.
Please try below code to put a 10 second timeout

```
System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts = new  System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource ();
 cts.CancelAfter (TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000));
var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<IRestResponse>();
 RestRequestAsyncHandle handle = RestClient.ExecuteAsync(request, response => { tcs.SetResult(response); })
 using (cts.Token.Register(() => handle.Abort()))
        {
        return (RestResponse)(await tcs.Task);
        }
```

Hope it helps!!